# Song won't load/play in the Flash Player

Tags: php, jquery, actionscript-3, flash

I am working on an online radio website. Here I use Flash Player which plays selected song from a list of songs (XML). The issue is that all songs are playing properly in Chrome, but when I try to play a song in other browsers its shows message as "Buffering..." but song won't load/play in the Flash Player.

Browsers that I am testing on are:

- 1.Mozilla( version 31.0)
- 2.Safari( version 31.0)
- 3.Chrome( Version 35.0.1916.153)
- 4.Opera( version 31.0)
- 5.Internet Explorer( 9.0 )

My Flash Player is a pure Actionscript 3 project compiled with Flex4.5 SDK ( I did not work on this part). There are always two SWF files shipped:

- player.swf (application SWF)
- player_skin.swf (skin/asset SWF containing all the visual elements of
  the player)

My site link: http://www1.977music.com/

- Buffering ss: http://screencast.com/t/jIqf47WNmCP

Please follow this steps to encounter the issue:

- Click on any stations which you'll see under the "Stations" tab.
  screenshot: http://screencast.com/t/ltzzzQ9v
- When you click on any station name, by default any random song from
  that station would start playing. But like I mentioned the songs
  don't play in Firefox and few other browsers, the player just
  displays the message "Buffering.." and nothing happens. No music.
  Whileas in Chrome the player plays perfectly fine.

I am clueless as to why this issue is come across only in certain browsers. I'm not even sure if it's related to the Flash Player or the PHP part written to pass songs via webservice to the player

Any clues anyone?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: FYI, it seems to work for me. Tested on Chrome, Safari, and Firefox (all latest stable versions) on OS X Mavericks.

Comment: Seems to work fine in Firefox and Chrome for me.

Comment: Seems to work for me as well. FF 31 and Safari 7.0.3. OS X 10.9

Comment: the problem does sound like an event catching issue. Maybe using ProgressEvent instead of complete to see if a file is completely loaded (bad practice and leading to the kind of issue you have). Also possible bad timing in registering event so they won't fire on time.

Comment: Thanks every one for your response.
Hello Mr. BotMaster
 I am using onClick() event in js when user clicks on a particular station name.

Could you please tell me, how can I debug it?